# What tax forms do I use?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I own my own business - Sole Proprietor. I have employees and pay quarterly taxes using form 941. I do not take a paycheck or draw from my business. I also work for someone else and receive a W2. What tax forms should I file?

Comment: What taxes are you asking about?